# optional flavours of a target

Tags: makefile

I want to manage some features and setup specific quirks at compile time. Thus, I must be able to modify the list of objects that have to be compiled to make the final target, the compile command and link command. So far I've been in need of using only two flavours of the program, where the other one (say `special`) one just added some `CXXFLAGS` and one object file:

```
specialclient: CXXFLAGS+=-DSPECIALBUILD
specialclient: LDFLAGS+=-lanotherlib
specialclient: libanotherlib client
```

where `client` is the normal target. But now that I need another selectable feature (say `peculiar`), things start to get complicate, because I want to be able to select any combination of the features; yet I don't want to specify targets for `peculiarclient` and `specialpeculiarclient`. I would like to be able to specify each feature in the command line, like `make [special] [peculiar] client`.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Some [conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals) should do the trick:

```
ifdef SPECIAL
CXXFLAGS+=-DSPECIALBUILD
LDFLAGS+=-lanotherlib
client: libanotherlib
endif

ifdef PECULIAR
CXXFLAGS+=-DPECULIARBUILD
LDFLAGS+=-lyetanotherlib
client: libyetanotherlib
endif
```

Now you can `make client`, `make client SPECIAL=1`, `make client PECULIAR=yes`, `make client SPECIAL=TRUE PECULIAR=very`, or whatever.